# ffmpeg add audio to left chanel , convert to mp4 and change the warper

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video-conversion

We have a Quicktime uncompressed file with no audio and 1 channel audio file.
At the end, I need 2 files:

- uncompress.mov with left audio
- Codec: h.264  Wrapper: .mov   Audio  on the left channel.

1. I need to add the audio to the left channel

   ```
   ffmpeg -i video.mov -i audio.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental video.mov
   ```
2. map the channel

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input -map_channel 0.0.0 output
   ```
3. convert to mp4

   ```
   ffmpeg -i my-video.mov -vcodec h264 -acodec mp2 my-video.mp4
   ```
4. out the mp4 to the wrapper.mov

   ```
   ffmpeg -i file.mp4 file.mov
   ```

Is that making sense or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

This command will convert a video file to `MPEG-4`, add an `mp3` to the output as the left audio channel, and save the result in a `mov` wrapper.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov \
       -i input.mp3 \
       -vcodec h264 \
       -acodec aac \
       -map_channel 1.0.0\
       -map_channel -1 \
       -map 0:0 -map 1:0 \
       -f mov output.mov
```

This command will add an `mp3` to the output as the left audio channel without changing the encoding of the original input video file.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov \
       -i input.mp3 \
       -vcodec copy \
       -acodec aac \
       -map_channel 1.0.0\
       -map_channel -1 \
       -map 0:0 -map 1:0 \
       -f mov output.mov
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to do this, and you can do it all in one command.

## -map_channel

You can use the `-map_channel` option:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mov -i audio.mp3 -map_channel 1.0.0 -map_channel -1 -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s16le uncompress.mov -map_channel 1.0.0 -map_channel -1 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac output.mov
```

The `-map_channel` values refer to `input file ID.stream specifier.channel ID`. For stereo `channel ID` left is `0` and right is `1`.

## pan filter

Or use the [pan filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mov -i audio.mp3 -af "pan=stereo|FL=FL" -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s16le uncompress.mov -af "pan=stereo|FL=FL" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac output.mov
```

Or use one instance of pan for both outputs:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mov -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a]pan=stereo|FL=FL,asplit[a0][a1]" -map 0:v -map "[a0]" -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s16le uncompress.mov -map 0:v -map "[a1]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac output.mov
```

#### Also see

- [FFmpeg Wiki: Audio Channel Manipulation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation)